# Command out of sync when i run stored procedure! using mysqli driver

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am Using Mysqli Driver.

I am getting Command out of sync when i try to run the stored procedure. I have tried

```
free_result();
```

this is the snippet of my code can any 1 tell me the solution?

```
function block()
{
    $qry = "CALL `sp_get_codes_by_block_id`(?)";
    $result = $this->db->query($qry, $this->getBlockId());
    $temp_array = array();
    $temp_array = $result;
    $result->free_result();
    return $result->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well i Actually figured out answer after alot of Brain storming and search.

```
   $qry = "CALL `sp_get_codes_by_block_id`(?)";
    $result = $this->db->query($qry, $this->getBlockId());
    mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id);
    return $result->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html says:

> Multiple-result processing also is required if you execute CALL statements for stored procedures.

I.e. you have to go through all result sets via [mysqli::more_results](http://docs.php.net/mysqli.next-result) and free all of them.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
while(mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id)) {
    if($result = mysqli_store_result($this->db->conn_id)){
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
}
```