# codeigniter : Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: codeigniter

I applied all the possible answers but still same problem.
also tried

```
$this->db->reconnect();
```

there is no problem in my query

[image]

MyCode:

```
public function GetdistributorsDetails($username){
        $sql = "SELECT u.FirstName, u.Email, u.Telephone, u.MobileNumber, u.AlternateMobileNumber, ud.Address1, ud.Pincode,ud.City,s.Statename FROM users u JOIN userdetails ud ON ud.UserId = u.UserId JOIN states s ON s.StateId = ud.StateId WHERE u.Username = ? ";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql,array($username));
        return $result->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Did you maybe make a query that uses a stored procedure earlier in the shown code?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632075/mysqli-giving-commands-out-of-sync-error-why

Comment: @qwertzman, Not really a duplicate as the OP is dealing with the database abstraction layer of codeigniter. That said, it is likely the problem and has been know to occur in CI when a stored procedure has just (or recently) been used. However, it may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647699/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now-while-calling-stored-proced and or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821377/command-out-of-sync-when-i-run-stored-procedure-using-mysqli-driver

Comment: yes i am using SP and it returns proper result but after that i need to fire this query so what's the problem?

Comment: Can any body explain why this happening and after using  
 mysqli_next_result( $this->db->conn_id ) 
it sorted out. But why ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

add following code into /system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php

```
 function next_result()
 {
     if (is_object($this->conn_id))
     {
         return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
     }
 }
```

then in model when you call Stored Procedure

```
$query    = $this->db->query("CALL test()");
$res      = $query->result();

//add this two line 
$query->next_result(); 
$query->free_result(); 
//end of new code

return $res;
```

Comment: This is a beautiful fix to a problem I've been trying to solve for a while now. Thank you Juned, really. I did need to add a check for next results to avoid potential errors.

Comment: Just update https://stackoverflow.com/a/65628126/10455858

Answer (score 6):

you can use this after call

```
mysqli_next_result( $this->db->conn_id );
```

Comment: Thank you for providing such awesome solution.
Kindly elaborate the above mentioned line of code if posssible.

Answer (score 2):

```
Here is example if you don't want change any thing in mysqli drivers files 

$sql = "CALL procedureName(IntParam,'VarcharParm1','VaracharParm2','VarcharParm3');";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
mysqli_next_result( $this->db->conn_id );
$query->free_result();

these are important line place after to remove the error 
mysqli_next_result( $this->db->conn_id );
$query->free_result();
```

Comment: This saves my day. Please explain how this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this one if you use multiple query make in same function:
$this->db->close();

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure returns more than one result, try to add this code between the queries:

```
$storedProcedure = 'CALL test(inputParam, @outputParam)';
$this->db->query($storedProcedure);    

$conn = $this->db->conn_id;
do {
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
} while (mysqli_more_results($conn) && mysqli_next_result($conn));

$sql = 'SELECT @outputParam;';
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add **next_result** function in
***system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_result.php*** file

```
public function next_result(){
    if(is_object($this->conn_id) && mysqli_more_results($this->conn_id)){
        return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
    }
}
```

To call query function

```
  $result = $this->db->query("CALL {$Name}({$Q})",$Param);
  $result->next_result();
  return  $result;
```