# store produre is not getting connection for running another query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I am using mysql version in codeigniter and applied stored procedure for one of database operation and after running this . i want to run another query . so how can i run other query below the store procedure or close the connection

getting this error

```
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

here is additional code

This is my store procedure

```
$ret = $CI->db->query("call test_type($item_id,$test_id)");
now I want to run this query
$query = $CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM testing WHERE testing.test_type in  ('" . $test_id . "') AND testing.test_item_id =  '" . $item_id . "' ORDER BY testing.test_date DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code.

Comment: This is my store procedure 
$ret = $CI->db->query("call test_type($item_id,$test_id)");
now I want to run this query
$query = $CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM testing WHERE testing.test_type in  ('" . $test_id . "') AND testing.test_item_id =  '" . $item_id . "' ORDER BY testing.test_date DESC LIMIT 1");

Comment: You should also update your question instead of posting additional code in comments. It's quite unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232250/codeigniter-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now).I am also facing error like you and solved using below code.

**add following code into /system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php**

```
 function next_result()
 {
     if (is_object($this->conn_id))
     {
         return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
     }
 }
```

**then in model when you call Stored Procedure**

```
$sql    = $this->db->query("CALL getCityList()");
$result      = $sql->result();

//add this two line 
$sql->next_result(); 
$sql->free_result(); 
//end of new code

return $result;
```