# Calling Stored Procedure inside foreach PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having an error when calling stored procedure inside foreach
It says "**Commands out of sync you can't run this command now**" .
I already looking for solution, but the result is not like i'm expecting.
This is my code

```
$query = "CALL PROCEDURE_HEAD()";
$sql   = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
foreach($sql as $key) {
   $name = $key['name'];
   $array['name'] = $name;
   $array['data'] = $key['data'];

   $query2 = "CALL PROCEDURE_CHILD('$name')";
   $sql2   = $this->db->query($query2)->result_array();

   foreach($sql2 as $value) {
     $array['child'] = array(
                        'child_name' => $value['child_name'],
                        'child_data' => $value['child_data']
                       );
   }
}
```

i have tried run [codeigniter : Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232250/codeigniter-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now), and because i'm using Procedure after Procedure,it doesn't run.
Any kind of help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Model with associate this

**In Controller**

```
$head = $this->Model_name->call_head();

foreach($head as $item) {
    $name = $item['name'];
    $array['name'] = $name;
    $array['data'] = $item['data'];

    $child = $this->Model_name->call_child($name);

    foreach($child as $value) {
        $array['child'] = array(
            'child_name' => $value['child_name'],
            'child_data' => $value['child_data']
           );
    }
}
```

**In model**

```
public function call_head()
{
    $query = "CALL PROCEDURE_HEAD()";
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    $query->next_result(); 
    $query->free_result();
    return $result;
}

public function call_child($name)
{
    $query = "CALL PROCEDURE_CHILD($name)";
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    $query->next_result(); 
    $query->free_result();
    return $result;
}
```